# How I can separate the Java Code from Drools rules in this situation?

Tags: java, drools

This is the scenario of what I'm doing in Drools.

There is a Java object - `PricingDetails`, containing a list of objects (`ServiceDrools`) that represent services.

Each `ServiceDrools` has the following fields:

- service (number)
- type of service (number)
- rate

What I need to do is according to the information of each `ServiceDrools`, to change the rate for each one, for example:

If a `ServiceDrools` has service 112 and type 9, or service 159 and type 4, then apply a 5% discount to the `ServiceDrools`.

The way I'm doing is:

```
rule "Test- service type 9, service 112 + service type 4, service 159"
   lock-on-active
when
    $detail : PricingDetails()
    $services : ArrayList( size > 1 ) from collect(
        ServiceDrools( (serviceType == 9 && service == 112) || 
                           (serviceType == 4 && service == 159) )
        from $detail.getServices()
    )
then
    modify( $detail ){
        setCostServices($services, .05);
    }
end
```

In the first part, the object `PricingDetails` is getting the list of services it contains, to cycle to find the services listed. The services that stisfy the condition are stored in the variable `$services`.

Then `PricingDetails` object is modified by calling the function `setCostServices($services, .05)`, which has the following code:

```
public void setCostServices(ArrayList<ServiceDrools> serviciosProcesar, 
                            Double porcentajeDescuento){
    Double suma = 0D;       
    for (ServicioDrools s: serviciosProcesar)
        suma += s.getTarifa();      
    Double nuevaTarifa = suma - (suma * porcentajeDescuento);       
    for (ServicioDrools s: serviciosProcesar)
        s.setTarifa( nuevaTarifa );     
}
```

How I can improve the code?
How I can separate the Java Code from Drools rules?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is method setCostServices defined ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. At least in the description you have provided, there is no unusual mixture of Java and DRL. The only time that should be a concern is if the LHS of the rule is doing complex logic using calls out to Java code. In this case, the setCostServices function is on the RHS, so that's not a concern.

Comment: The only problem I see is that the setCostServices function does not look like it works in the fashion described. It is not applying a 5% discount to each service tariff. It is setting the tariff of each service to be 5% less than the sum of all service tariffs. That and the code provided is a Java method, whereas the rule appears to be calling it as a DRL function. All of which leads me to think that the code provided just does not work.